# Nested Dictonary List to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to convert a nested dictionary (list) into a csv file. When I run my code, it is not the ideal output. The code below yields the folowing output:

```
type    name    color   ownerinfo
cat    fred     blue    [{'name': 'Mary,'phonenumber':'123}]
cat     ben    orange   [{'name':'Dan', 'phonenumber':'234'}]
```

however I would like the output to be

```
type    name    color    name   phonenumber
cat    fred     blue       Mary   123
cat     ben    orange      Dan    234
```

````
import json
import pandas as pd

#Open and laod files as list
with open("data.json", "rb") as f:
    data = json.load(f)["objects"]

# Get cat
cats = [a for a in data if "cat in a.get("type")]

df = pd.DataFrame(cats)
#store cat in csv
df.to_csv('in.csv')```
````

Comment: What does `data.json` look like? (or `df`). Hard to understand what we are working with having to backward engineer your non-working code.

Comment: Use `pd.DataFrame.json_normalize`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Comment: Did you copy your code correctly? You’re missing a closed quote after *cat* in your list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a second data frame from your nested column, then concatenate them into one. Here is a sample code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cats) # your final df in the question
temp_df = pd.DataFrame([r[0] for r in df['ownerinfo']]) # convert the column into a data frame
new_df = pd.concat([df.drop('ownerinfo', axis=1), temp_df], axis=1) # merge them
new_df.to_csv("/path/to/csv", index=False) # export to file
```

You can just add it before the export line to create a new one.